# Java while loop updating the condition?

Tags: java, while-loop

Is there a way to update the condition in a while loop?
In the below code, updating j if someCondition has been met?
So that that the initial loop doesn't loop for 20 times,
but rather it loops for 20+n times whenever someCondition.

```
public class foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 20;
        while(i < j) {
            //do something
            i++
            if(someCondition) {
                j++;    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Show real code as well.

Comment: This is not clear. I think you need to explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't have an exact problem, was just wondering if there could be a way to update the condition after compile time in java programs.

Comment: But your code does that. Initially the condition is `i < 20` but later it changes to `i < 21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a do/while loop, which compares values after executing the code

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. just try it and you will see that you can.
even more, you can change i inside `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`, there is no problem with this kind of changes.

Comment: if you change i of course it won't change n. but you can also change n if you want to. you can do something like `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) if(condition) n++;`

Comment: No, the n stays what the value of n was initially, n does not change once inside of the for loop.

Comment: did you even try this before say it don't work? try the next code, if you are right it will print just 1 - 20:
`int n=20; for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {System.out.println(i); n++;}`